# Is string::swap ignorable because of std::swap(s1, s2) is enough?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

`std::string` has a member function `swap`, which had been an efficient means to swap two big strings.

Now that we have move-semantics, so, given two big strings `s1` and `s2`, the following code

`s1.swap(s2);`

should be identical to the following code in terms of efficiency:

`std::swap(s1, s2);`

Is `string::swap` ignorable?

Comment: "deprecated" is a heavy word.

Comment: `std::swap` is usually implemented as calling the member swap. It's not really clear what it has to do with move semantics.

Comment: @Csq, `std::swap(T& a, T& b)` can be implemented as `T tmp = std::move(a); a = std::move(b); b = std::move(tmp);`

Comment: `std::swap` is overloaded (or specialized or whatever) for `std::string` already, so it will probablly call `std::string::swap`

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed.

Comment: @NeilKirk, if the string's move-semantics has been implemented correctly, the specialized version `std::swap(string& a, string& b)` is unnecessary.

Comment: True, but whether `std::string::swap` is ignorable or not doesn't depend on move-semantics. It was always equally unnecessary. The question could be more broadly asked - what is the point of `std::string::swap` when we have `std::swap`

Comment: @xmllmx You still have to create empty strings for the moved-from objects. `string::swap` does not do that. (Of course it is likely to be optimized out anyway.)

Comment: @xmllmx The specialized version avoids the unnecessary construction and destruction of a temporary string.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The question "Is it time to deprecate `string::swap`?" has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `string::swap` ignorable?

You may choose to ignore it if you wish to, and always call non-member `swap`; the effect will be identical to calling `string::swap` because the `swap` specialization for `basic_string` is described in terms of the member function.

*§21.4.8.8 [string.special]*

> ```
>   template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator> void
>   swap(basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
>        basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
> ```
>
> 1 *Effects:* Equivalent to `lhs.swap(rhs);`

My personal opinion is to evaluate the options on a case-by-case basis and use whichever seems to be better suited for a given occasion.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecating *anything* is more or less a lost cause.  For backwards compatibility compiler vendors can't really *get rid of* anything -- or a valued customer is sure to complain.

Comment: It looks like talk of deprecation has been removed from the question.

Comment: OP depricated deprication ;)